# How to return a value using return

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

Very confused why the `return` function doesn't return my variable to the screen when I run it using pycharm. the `print` function works perfectly fine but I'm trying to use `return` when writing functions. any help appreciated. here is the code I'm trying with:

```
def disemvowel(string):
    message = []
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    for letter in string:
        if letter not in vowels:
            message.append(letter)
    return message

disemvowel('laol')
```

if I substitute `return` with `print` it works the way I intend it to work

Once again any help appreciated

Comment: `return` does not print to the screen. But there is a feature in the interactive interpreter (only) that prints the result of the line interpreted to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to print the result:

```
print(disemvowel('laol'))
```

The result of an expression (i.e. the returned value in this case) isn't printed, except in an interactive session.